# How can I read in a file from the Downloads/Documents folder in iOS with my flutter app?

Tags: ios, flutter, file, mobile, permissions

I am using one app to save a files to the local device storage. I then want to read that file in with my Flutter app.

When I open the 'Files' app on iOS, I can confirm the files exists when I go to "On My Phone".

I have written the following two functions in my Flutter app. The documents directory returns a list of size 0, and the downloads directory does not exist at all (even though is actually does).

```
void printAllFilesInDocsDir() async {
    try {
      var docsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      List<FileSystemEntity> files = docsDir.listSync();
      for (FileSystemEntity file in files) {
        print(file.path);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print("Failed to read file: $e");
    }
  }

  void printAllFilesInDownloadsDir() async {
    try {
      var docsDir = await getDownloadsDirectory();
      List<FileSystemEntity> files = docsDir!.listSync();
      for (FileSystemEntity file in files) {
        print(file.path);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print("Failed to read file: $e");
    }
  }
```

I have added the following to my info.plist.

```
key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your photo library</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your microphone</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your camera</string>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your calendar</string>
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your contacts</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your location</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your location</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your location</string>
    <key>NSFileProviderDomainUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access files on your device</string>
```

Comment: You will need to find a flutter package that wraps `UIPickerViewController` so that the user can select the file. An app is not permitted to read files outside of its sandbox without user interaction.